# $(".grid").mouseenter doesn't run after I create new divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My $(".grid").mouseenter doesn't run after I press my new button, which deletes old divs (.grid) and creates new ones. So, what can I change to make it work after that. Also, why are there empty spaces above all .grid divs?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    createGrid();
    $(".grid").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass("hovered")
    });
    $("#new").click(function(){
        clear();
        createGrid(prompt("How big would you like your new grid to be (x<64)?"));
    });
    $("#clear").click(function(){
        clear();
    });
});
function clear(){
    $(".grid").removeClass("hovered");
};
function gridSize(measuring, howBig){
    if (howBig==null){
        howBig = 16;
    }
    switch(measuring){
        case "height":
            return parseInt($("#surface").height()/howBig);
        case "width":
            return parseInt($("#surface").width()/howBig);
    }
};
function createGrid(howBig){
    $("#surface").empty();
    if(howBig == null || howBig == ""){
        for(var i=0; i < 16; i++){
            $("#surface").prepend("<div class = 'grid' style = 'width: " +gridSize('width')+"px ; height:"+gridSize('height')+ "px;'></div>");
            for(var j=0; j < 15; j++){
                $("#surface").prepend("<div class = 'grid' style = 'width: " +gridSize('width')+"px ; height:"+gridSize('height')+ "px;'></div>");
            }
        }
    }
    else { 
        for(var i=0; i < howBig; i++){
            $("#surface").prepend("<div class = 'grid' style = 'width: " +gridSize('width', howBig)+"px ; height:"+gridSize('height', howBig)+ "px;'></div>");
            for(var j=0; j < howBig-1; j++){
                $("#surface").prepend("<div class = 'grid' style = 'width: " +gridSize('width', howBig)+"px ; height:"+gridSize('height', howBig)+ "px;'></div>");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
.wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#reset {
    width: 60px;
    margin : 15px auto;
}
#surface {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
}
.grid {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.hovered {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href = "css/styles.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "wrapper">
        <button id ="new">New</button>
        <button id ="clear">Clear</button>
        <div id = "surface"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
$(".grid").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hovered")
});
```

with

```
$("#surface").on('mouseenter','.grid',function(){
    $(this).addClass("hovered")
});
```

This is required because your original code was attaching event handlers to the `.grid` elements, which you delete and create new elements (which don't have the handlers attached).  You could just re-run your original code to attach new handlers when you create new elements, but using event delegation is a much better approach as you only attaching an event handler on one element (`#surface`) rather than on each individual `.grid` element, and of course, since you aren't removing and recreating the `#surface` element, you don't need to detach/re-attach it when you create a new grid.

You can read more about jQuery's `on` method and event delegation here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

As for the spacing issue, it is because you are using inline-block elements, and inline-elements will preserve atleast one space if present between elements.  You can either remove all spaces (and line breaks) between the elements, or you can place `font-size:0;` on the `#surface` element to shrink the space size to nothing.

```js
maxSize=16;
$(document).ready(function(){
    createGrid(16);
    $("#surface").on('mouseenter','div',function(){
        $(this).addClass("hovered")
    });
    $("#new").click(function(){
        createGrid(prompt("How big would you like your new grid to be (x<" + maxSize + ")?"));
    });
    $("#clear").click(function(){
        $("#surface>div").removeClass("hovered");
    });
});
function gridSize(measuring, howBig){
    switch(measuring){
        case "height":
            return parseInt($("#surface").height()/howBig);
        case "width":
            return parseInt($("#surface").width()/howBig);
    }
};
function createGrid(howBig){
    howBig=parseInt(howBig);
    if(howBig == NaN || howBig<1 || howBig>maxSize){
      howBig=16;
    }
    $("#surface").empty();
    for(var i=0; i < howBig*howBig; i++){
      $("#surface").append("<div style='width:" +gridSize('width', howBig)+"px; height:"+gridSize('height', howBig)+ "px;'></div>");
    }
};
```

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
.wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#reset {
    width: 60px;
    margin : 15px auto;
}
#surface {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    font-size: 0;
}
#surface>div {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
#surface>div.hovered {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <button id="new">New</button>
        <button id="clear">Clear</button>
        <div id="surface"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also taken the liberty to clean up some of the javascript for you.

Comment: Probably better to use `#surface` instead of `body`.

Comment: Yes, it is. I didn't analyze the code enough to determine the closest non-changing container.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use event delegation  to work with dynamically created elements

```
$("#surface").on('mouseenter','.grid',function(){
     $(this).addClass("hovered");
});
```

`--->` https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1):

it does not work because the divs created after you attach the action to it so you must to use one of this statements :

**Example 1:**

```
$("body").on('mouseenter','.grid',function(){
     $(this).addClass("hovered");
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

**Example 2:**

```
$("body").live('mouseenter','.grid',function(){
     $(this).addClass("hovered");
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

**Example 3:**

```
$("body").delegate('mouseenter','.grid',function(){
     $(this).addClass("hovered");
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/